# How can I check if my AVPlayer is Playing, Connecting or Buffering?

Tags: swift, avplayer, audio-streaming

I am building application which play an audio stream using AVPlayer.

I would like to know how can I handle Buffering states, Re-connecting(if internet fail).

I would like to know how and when I can show hide loading indicator.

I can't find anything in the documentation for AVPlayer.

Thanks